# Set Parent view (xaml, maui)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xaml, maui

I have a main layout with a content view that I want to populate with a bunch a different views.

I thought I would set the parent view from the child, but I haven't figured out how. There may be a better way to accomplish this though.

Layout file:

```
<ContentPage ...>

<Grid RowDefinitions="*,Auto,*">
...
<ContentView x:Name="ViewToPopulate"
    Grid.Row="1"/>
...
</ContentPage>
```

Sublayout file:

```
<ContentView ...
    Parent="StaticResource ViewToPopulate">

<GridView >
...
</GridView>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: You add the child to the parent, not the other way around

Comment: Then how do I dynamically set the ContentView in the layout file to be whichever view I need?

Comment: I'd do it in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Jason said, you don't set the parent from the child.
I found the best way to do this is follow this suggestion that @Jason also made in the comment of:
[Header and Footer in .NET MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74668855/header-and-footer-in-net-maui)